# "The Parameter Is Incorrect" MFC exception

Tags: c++, exception, mfc

This is native C++. No .NET framework involved.

I am trying to figure out which exception is thrown when the CListBox gets an invalid parameter. Turns out MFC uses this exception quite a lot but I can't determine the actual exception type thrown. I have tried a lot of different types on the catch (int, const char *, std:*) but the only one besides catch(...) that catches it is the (const void *). Looking the memory structure, I still don't have a clue what is actually thrown.
Does any one know what it is or how to determine what it thrown?

This is a sample MFC application. ListBox is a CListBox. The application is nothing more than the default DialogBox based MFC application that VS builds automatically. The only change is that I added a list box and the code you see below in the OK button handler.

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    try
    {
        CString Value;
        ListBox.GetText( -1, Value );
        Value = "none";
    }
    catch ( CException & exception )
    {
            exception.Delete();
    }
    catch ( const void * e )
    {
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

Comment: The memory block pointed to by the void * always contains this string of bytes: 4c b5 8f 59 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 57 00 07 80 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ee fe ee fe

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I bet it is a member variable of type `CListBox` ;-P

Comment: I don't think an exception should be thrown from `GetText`.  From the MSDN docs: "If nIndex does not specify a valid index, the return value is LB_ERR."  Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6kt91ff.aspx

Comment: @rodrigo: well, it shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: Try running under [Application Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028).

Comment: all I can think of is that you corrupted that variable...

Comment: Set up your debugger to break whenever any exception is **thrown** (*Debug* -> *Exceptions*). At that point you have the full callstack available, and can inspect the MFC source code.

Comment: Richard Critten, the method use is the one that uses a CString reference. This method has no return value.

Comment: Try casting the `void*` to a `CObject*` and call `CObject::Dump`, as in `((CObject*)e)->Dump(afxDump)`.

Comment: IInspectable, Thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: Exceptions thrown by MFC are always of type `CException *` or one of its subclasses. See [CException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx1b5f5w.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To explain why you get the exception, it looks like when you use the `CString` version of `CListBox::GetText()` it will throw an E_INVALIDARG exception if the passed index is not valid. Tracing through the MFC code is a bit of work but `CListBox::GetText()` looks like:

```
void CListBox::GetText(int nIndex, CString& rString) const
{
        ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));
        GetText(nIndex, rString.GetBufferSetLength(GetTextLen(nIndex)));
        rString.ReleaseBuffer();
}
```

`CListBox::GetTextLen(-1)` will return `LB_ERR` which is `-1`. If you follow the code for `CString::GetBufferSetLength()` you eventually end up in `CString::SetLength()`:

```
void SetLength(_In_ int nLength)
{
      ATLASSERT( nLength >= 0 );
      ATLASSERT( nLength <= GetData()->nAllocLength );

      if( nLength < 0 || nLength > GetData()->nAllocLength)
             AtlThrow(E_INVALIDARG);

      GetData()->nDataLength = nLength;
      m_pszData[nLength] = 0;
}
```

with `nLength == -1` and thus the exception.

Comment: That is very interesting. I had seen the CString error before when setting the length to -1 would throw this exception. Given that this particular error happens with combo boxes too, then does this indicate that the likely root of all E_INVALIDARG errors are with CString if one digs down far enough ?

Comment: That would a good guess, either that or a similar function throwing an invalid argument exception.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
catch ( const COleException * e )
```

I was using `catch ( const COleException & e )` as all the text books say one should. Oh well.

Details can be found at [Exception Handling in MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t078xe4f.aspx), and [Exceptions: Catching and Deleting Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5twxsh.aspx) in particular.

Comment: MFC was written at a time when exception support couldn't be guaranteed in the compiler. Throwing pointers instead of actual objects made it possible to emulate the whole process with macros. Since Microsoft are the kings of backwards compatibility, they never changed it.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not so worried about non-standard patterns to support backwards compatibility, as I am about the lacking documentation. MFC has never been good in this department. The description for [CListBox::GetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6kt91ff.aspx) should have mentioned, that one of the overloads can throw exceptions. Of course, when you have a return type `void` for a method that can fail, an exception is somewhat expected.

Comment: It would have been nice if the documentation had stated the exception explicitly. Also I would be nice if the documentation for COleException pointed out that it's throwing a pointer and not an object. But in any case thank you all so very much especially IInspectable. This is a lesson I will not soon forget.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this **invalid argument exception** can now happen through a call to `UpdateAllViews()`.  I traced the code deep through the **`MFC libraries`**.  It results from a `macro` that only generates the throw for release builds.

Since it is so deep, it can occur from several other functions.